# How to install/configure python 3.7 on Amazon1 EC2 instance (Cloud9)?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I am using AWS Cloud9 Amazon1 (EC2) instance.

Python 2.7 is pre-installed.

I am not sure where the python 3.7 is to be installed - home dir or root dir? Can someone help me with the steps to install python 3.7 such that it meets the following criteria:

> If Python 3.7 is installed on the device, name the binary 'python3.7'
> and add its parent  directory to the PATH environment variable.

Note that `apt-get` is not supported. `yum` works.

**Update**:

I have followed the steps from answer and installed python 3.7 successfully and checked by firing `python3.7 -V`. However, the dependency checker is unable to detect the python 3.7:

```
mkdir greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.11.x
cd greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.11.x
wget https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-greengrass-samples/raw/master/greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.11.x.zip
unzip greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.11.x.zip
cd greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.11.x
sudo ./check_ggc_dependencies | more
```

Comment: AL1 is rather old. Probably have to compile it as shown [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-amazon-linux/).

Comment: I just followed https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/, it is exactly the same as your link, if you can add the steps as an answer then I can mark this questions as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

There is no native package for python 3.7 on Amazon Linux 1. Thus, it should be compiled as shown [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/). The compilation steps include:

1. Installation of dependencies,

```
yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel
```

2. Downloading python source:

```
cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
```

3. Extract Python-3.7.9

```
tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
```

4. Compilation

```
cd Python-3.7.9
./configure --enable-optimizations
make altinstall
```

5. Cleanup

```
rm /usr/src/Python-3.7.9.tgz
```

### Update

Need to sym link pyhton:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7
```

[image]

Comment: Python 3.7 successfully as confirmed when I run `python3.7 -V`. However, the dependency checker (see question update) is unable to detect the python 3.7. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be something to do with user level or system level installation?

Comment: There is no error, just that the dependency checker (see question update) is unable to detect that python is installed. It returns: `Python 3.7: Not found`

Comment: Prior to step 3 can you add `tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz` to unzip

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to either:

- [Compile it from source](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/)
- [Use pyenv that will compile it too](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: I have managed to install it but the dependency checked (see question) is unable to detect it

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the Cloud9 environment from the console (web browser instead of CloudFormation) then you can now use Amazon Linux 2. That should have a more up to date set of tools installed.